# Angular controller not initialized in jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angular-ui-router

I ran into issues writing jasmine tests for an AngularJS application using angular ui-router. My services and app get initialized properly in the test, but the controllers do not start up properly. I've taken the application in question out of the equation and reduced the problem to a simple one controller example that exhibits the same behavior. Here's the actual test code:

```
describe('Test', function() {
    var async = new AsyncSpec(this);
    var scope = {};

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('TestApp'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $state, $templateCache) {
        scope.$rootScope  = $rootScope;
        scope.$state      = $state;

        $templateCache.put('start.html', '<div class="start"></div>');
    }));

    async.it('Test that TestCtrl is initialized', function(done) {
        scope.$rootScope.status = { done: false };
        scope.$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, state, params) {
            expect(scope.$rootScope.status.done).toBe(true);
            done();
        });
        scope.$state.transitionTo('start', {}, { notify: true });
        scope.$rootScope.$apply();
    });
});
```

Here's the complete runnable [test](http://jsfiddle.net/C8QtB/2/)

The application gets initialized correctly, the ui router is able to transition the application to the correct state, but the controller does not get initialized. I need the router to initialize the controllers as the router passes critical configuration to them. I want to avoid duplicating that configuration in the tests.

I must be missing something, but what? I appreciate any and all input, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the $controller service to instantiate your controller in your tests and pass it your scope. For example...

```
ctrl = $controller('TestCtrl', {$scope: scope});
```

Notice that I also moved the declaration of $rootScope.done to the TestCtrl to prevent an error about $rootScope.done being undefined. Here's the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/C8QtB/3/

Comment: Thanks, but this unfortunately does not completely resolve my issue. I need to have ui-router instantiate the controllers. This is because the router configures the controllers (resolve parameters to be exact). So I wanted to use the router in the tests to avoid duplicating the controller configuration in each test. My bad for leaving that out of my question. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: You are going to have to do it the way I described using the $controller service. You aren't duplicating it in every test. It's in a before each hook, so it will automatically run before each test, which is the appropriate way. Tests should be stand alone and not rely on previous tests to succeed. Your routes won't instantiate your controller in unit tests, because you aren't actually navigating to any route. If you want to test that routes instantiate a controller, you should do it in an integration test. Mock the value provided by the route resolve parameter and inject it into your test.

Comment: Actually, I am attempting to navigate in that test; See the $state.transitionTo() call. That call ends up loading template files, but the controllers are not initialized nevertheless. Sure, I wouldn't have to do that for every test, but I will surely have separate test files for different parts of the app and I would end up either duplicating the initialization code in each file, or coming up with a base test of sorts which I would use in each test. I would've preferred ui-router to do this for me.

Comment: I think your tests are going beyond the scope of unit tests. If you want to test the changing of states, you should do it in an integration test. Unit tests are supposed to test a single component in isolation. This means you test a single 'unit' or in angular terms a single controller, service or directive. Changing states in a unit test means you are testing at least 2 controllers in one unit test. Also, why bother testing that the router instantiates the controller? This functionality is a part of angular and is already tested in the angular tests. You should trust it. Just my two cents...

Comment: Fair point about going beyond the scope of unit tests. I'm not really interested in testing the transitions. but mereley looking for a mechanism to get controllers configured as they are in real use cases. Thanks for the discussion!